# How to complete the code to get the output's first row only from a wikipedia page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

The following code displays some output. From it, how to get the first row only?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = u'https://ta.wikisource.org/w/index.php?title=அட்டவணை பேச்சு:நாடகக்கலை-2.pdf&action=history'
content = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
#talkPage1 = soup.findAll(id='mw-content-text')
talkPage2 = soup.findAll(id='mw-history-compare')

for link in talkPage2:
    print(link.text)
```

The output:-

```
(நடப்பு | முந்திய) 05:56, 23 பெப்ரவரி 2018‎ Info-farmerBot (பேச்சு | பங்களிப்புகள்)‎ . . (வெற்று) (-4)‎ . . (-) (மீளமை) (அடையாளம்: Blanking)
(நடப்பு | முந்திய) 05:55, 23 பெப்ரவரி 2018‎ Info-farmerBot (பேச்சு | பங்களிப்புகள்)‎ . . (4 எண்ணுன்மிகள்) (+4)‎ . . (gdeg) (மீளமை)
.
.
.
.
(நடப்பு | முந்திய) 13:17, 28 ஜனவரி 2016‎ Info-farmer (பேச்சு | பங்களிப்புகள்)‎ . . (129 எண்ணுன்மிகள்) (+129)‎ . . (பகுப்பு:மின்னூல்கள்-பொதுகள உரிமம்-துப்புரவு‎)
```

The output that we need only the first row as follows:-

```
(நடப்பு | முந்திய) 05:56, 23 பெப்ரவரி 2018‎ Info-farmerBot (பேச்சு | பங்களிப்புகள்)‎ . . (வெற்று) (-4)‎ . . (-) (மீளமை) (அடையாளம்: Blanking)
```

Comment: Sou use `soup.find()` and only get the first result.

Comment: And `soup.findAll()` returns a Python list, so the other obvious approach would be to use indexing, `print(talkPage2[0].text)`.

Comment: Kindly excuse me. Not able to get. Your full recode please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = u'https://ta.wikisource.org/w/index.php?title=அட்டவணை பேச்சு:நாடகக்கலை-2.pdf&action=history'
content = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
# talkPage1 = soup.findAll(id='mw-content-text')
talkPage2 = soup.find(id='mw-history-compare').find('li')  # narrows it down to list items instead of the whole list

print(talkPage2.text)
```

Output:

```
(நடப்பு | முந்திய) 05:56, 23 பெப்ரவரி 2018‎ Info-farmerBot (பேச்சு | பங்களிப்புகள்)‎ . . (வெற்று) (-4)‎ . . (-) (மீளமை) (அடையாளம்: Blanking)
```

Is this what you were looking for? You were printing the whole list before, I think maybe you meant you were looking for the first *list item* of the list. This is what that looks for.

Answer (score -1):

Add `break` in the `for` loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = u'https://ta.wikisource.org/w/index.php?title=அட்டவணை பேச்சு:நாடகக்கலை-2.pdf&action=history'
content = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
#talkPage1 = soup.findAll(id='mw-content-text')
talkPage2 = soup.findAll(id='mw-history-compare')

for link in talkPage2:
    print(link.text)
    break
```

This will give you only the first line.

Comment: It gives all the rows

Comment: Does it really?

Comment: @Arusekk, you should read the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). There are better methods available for getting the first element (instead of looping over all and `break`ing after first). Check the [`find()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) method.